# Newton's laws in non inertial frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames

Suppose we take a two particle system in CM frame such that the particles are connected by a massless spring and a force $F$ is applied on one particle ($m_1$ and $m_2$. Let $F$ acting on $m_2$). Now if we try to study application of Newton's laws in accelerated CM frame we use pseudo force to use second law? Does spring force become external or internal in free body diagrams of individual particles?

As per me, I would prefer thinking spring force acting on individual particles even in CM frame. Only thing a spring force won't do is to accelerate CM. I need your inputs to know if my understanding of non inertial frames and Newton's laws application is alright? We may take some other examples of some em variable force acting between two particles in place of a spring. The confusion persists!

Comment: Pseudo-forces are the result of non-inertial coordinate systems, but they are not real forces. It's not a good idea to try to express the fact that one is describing physics in a non-inertial frame by introducing them as actual forces into free body diagrams.

Comment: That is fine. If you make a free body diagram of a particle in non inertial frame such as CM , would you show spring or em force as acting on fbd or discard them as being internal to CM system?

Comment: I wouldn't do free body diagrams, at all, and neither will you once you can do Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I don't know if OP has reached that stage in his physics learning (for if he has, he probably wouldn't have posted this question in the first place). In high school and undergad physics courses, before they teach analytical mechanics, they do make students solve problems in non-inertial reference frames using free body diagrams.

Comment: @Cicero: Been there, done that. IMHO it's a bad, bad, bad idea.

Comment: @CuriousOne I agree, but its an unfortunate reality in high school and undergrad physics courses.

Comment: @Cicero: Which still doesn't mean that I have to support or stay quiet about it...

Comment: To cut it short some books as I see now show spring force and some don't. I would prefer to show spring or em force as in fbd of particle it is clearly s external force.

Answer (score 3):

Let me recall what Newton's laws are, to start with:

1) In the universe exists at least one reference frame (that we call inertial) where $\textbf{v}= \textrm{const.}$ whenever no external interactions act on the particle. All other reference frames (if any) moving at constant speed wrt this very one will be inertial as well.

2) In the above reference frames (if any) whenever external interactions $\textbf{F}(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}})$ act, it holds $\textbf{F}(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}}) = \dot{\textbf{p}}$.

3) The sum of all mutual interactions acting on a system of particles is zero.

If you have non-inertial frames the best way to calculate what the dynamics are is to start from the positions of the particles and take derivatives, to make velocities and accelerations appear. Once you take such derivatives (twice) you will see that some of them involve the reference frames moving (which we call *non-inertial* forces) and some others are exactly nothing but $\dot{\textbf{p}}$. Therefore you will end up with an equation like:
$$
\dot{\textbf{p}} = \sum (\textrm{non-inertial forces}) +  \textbf{F}(\textbf{x},\dot{\textbf{x}})
$$
which in principle splits the *real* forces from the *non-inertial* ones. Then what you may want to call which is up to you; nevertheless the dynamics will be given by the solutions of the above.